# Google Polymer with Rails menu not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, polymer

I'm trying to use Google Polymer in a Rails app. I'm using the gem emcee (https://github.com/ahuth/emcee) and I have the core installed.

I am trying to just setup the scaffolding element to see how it works. However, I can't get the menu to expand when the window is small (mobile). The button just doesn't work. Javascript is loading because without it nothing works. I tried removing everything I could think about that would be causing problems.

You can see the problem on EDIT: removed link (no longer valid)

Note that I've tried removing all other JS besides platform.js and even all css.

Besides the button not working, the page starts dark when scaled small.

I'm also using Rails 4.0.2 and Ruby 2.1.2.

Comment: Were you using turbolinks? Did you ever get this resolved? @EmbMicro

Comment: This problem still persists for me, even if I use recent files....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I updated to the newest version, this problem went away. I'm not sure if it was a bug or something I did wrong the first time, but it works now.

Comment: Could you please provide a working scaffold? (application.{js,html} and scaffold of the drawer-panel?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the required 'custom' javascript?

```
document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
  var navicon = document.getElementById('navicon');
  var drawerPanel = document.getElementById('drawerPanel');
  navicon.addEventListener('click', function() {
  drawerPanel.togglePanel();
});
});
```